# The error I am getting is as follows: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: line 428: 4052 Segmentation fault $EXEC_CMD "$CMD"

Tags: ejabberd

Having trouble creating opensrf users during the configuration stage in the command line. The error I am getting is as follows:
/usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: line 428: 4052 Segmentation fault $EXEC_CMD "$CMD"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be related to AppArmor. There's a [comment on bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ejabberd/+bug/1659801/comments/3) which resolved the issue for me, I quote:

To solve the error, I opened the apparmor configuration file:

> nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ejabberdctl

Found the string:

> /bin/su                                 r,

And changed it by adding m:

> /bin/su                                 rm,

Restarted apparmor:

> sudo service apparmor restart

Credit : [Viacheslav Hapon](https://ixnfo.com/en/troubleshooting-usr-sbin-ejabberdctl-line-428-14615-segmentation-fault.html)

Comment: Thank for giving a solution

Comment: You're welcome :) Would be nice of you if you could accept the answer and give an upvote!

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by **yerforkferchips** is working, BUT if you are facing this problem, it means you are running ejabberd 16.XX which has [other known bugs you will encounter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152437/ejabberd-why-is-websocket-connection-not-opening).

I would recommend updating to the lastest version, otherwise you might waste precious days as I just did.