# Getting Error while reinstalling ejabbered XMPP server to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

we were trying to reinstall XMPP ejabbered server using below commands but we are getting error as attached.

Commands we are executing on our server are below:

Step 1: sudo apt-get update

Step 2: sudo apt-get -y install ejabberd

Step 3: sudo ejabberdctl register admin localhost ejabberdpass123

Step 4: sudo service ejabberd restart

we are also copying or yml file for backup purpose.

we have also verify that our ports 5280 and 5222 are open.

I have also review below article but still no solution i found.

[The error I am getting is as follows: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: line 428: 4052 Segmentation fault $EXEC_CMD "$CMD"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705053/the-error-i-am-getting-is-as-follows-usr-sbin-ejabberdctl-line-428-4052-segm)

Error screenshot is like below :
[image]

Comment: Check the journal log

Comment: Check also if ejabberd generates ejabberd.log or error.log files, or erl_crash.dump

Comment: I have checked no error log generated